# How to plot ROC curve with scikit learn for the multiclass case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to plot the ROC curve for the multiclass case for my own dataset. By the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#example-model-selection-plot-roc-py) I read that the labels must been binary(I have 5 labels from 1 to 5), so I followed the example provided in the documentation:

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier



from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False, ngram_range=(2,2))
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, cross_val_score

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv',
                     header=0, sep=',', names=['id', 'content', 'label'])


X = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['content'].values)
y = df['label'].values




# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[1,2,3,4,5])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

# Add noisy features to make the problem harder
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# shuffle and split training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33
                                                    ,random_state=0)

# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                                 random_state=random_state))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

# Plot of a ROC curve for a specific class
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[2])
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()

# Plot ROC curve
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
         label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]))
for i in range(n_classes):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
                                   ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Some extension of Receiver operating characteristic to multi-class')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

The problem with this is that this aproach never finish. Any idea of how to plot this ROC curve for this [dataset](http://pastebin.com/KWALx8PM)?.

Comment: I think you have a conceptual bug. ROC is really undefined for anything other than two classes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @carlosdc. Sure it's only for the binary classification case. So it is impossible to plot this?

Comment: You could do a pair-wise ROC curve for each pair of classes.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/how-to-plot-roc-curves-in-multiclass-classification

Comment: The link to your dataset seems to be broken.

Comment: Does someone know how to plot this in case of multiclass and cross validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version never finishes because this line:

```
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=random_state))
```

The svm classifier takes a really long time to finish, use a different classifier like AdaBoost or another of your choice:

```
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(AdaBoostClassifier())
```

Remember to add an import:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
```

Remove this code, it's useless:

```
# Add noisy features to make the problem harder
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]
```

Instead just add:

```
random_state = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, why does this take so much with SVMs?

Comment: It's because you set probabilities to True. In such a case, svm has to compute the probabilities as well, which is memory- and computational-intensive.

Comment: @Eranyogev How do you plot this for multiclass with cross validation?